# ZIP: What are the temporary binary files which names start with `zi`?

Tags: linux, mac, bash, zip, binary-files

While I am zipping a subdirectory in a given directory, two binary files appeared in this location which are called `zietrLSl` and `ziwvPwKm` and disappeared when the `zip` command ended. At another directory, the same happend but with only a single binary file called `zi9Rt6a4`.

- Why does zip need these binary files?
- Are they named `zi` followed by random characters or do their name mean anything specific?

---

I used the command

```
zip -r mydir.zip mydir
```

for both cases. If needed, I am on `MAC OS X 10.11.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zip` program writes a *temporary* file meanwhile it works.
It puts this file in the same directory where the zip file has to be created. 
Then it will rename it with the final name.

From `man zip` you can specify the path:

> **--temp-path path**
>            Use the specified path for the temporary zip archive. For example:
>
> ```
>    zip -b /tmp stuff *
> ```
>
> will  put  the  temporary  zip  archive in the directory /tmp, copying over stuff.zip to the current directory when done. This option is useful when updating an existing archive and the file system containing this old archive does not have enough space to hold both old and new archives at the same time.  It may also  be  useful  when  streaming  in some cases to avoid the need for data descriptors.  Note that using this option may require zip take additional time to copy the archive file when done to the destination file system.

So in brief: it is needed, it is the file that you are creating, You can check it doing

```
file ziPbmVnZ
```

that will answer with

```
ziPbmVnZ: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

The name of the *temporary* file usually starts with **zi**-something.